# Use Jade Language in Client Side which should be compiled in server-side without affecting conditionals

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I just want to use Jade Lang in client side, but it should be compiled to pure html and JavaScript keeping all conditional like **if-else**, **unless** and "**=**" used in client-side and server side. How to do it?

```
if name == "Bob"
    h1 hello Bob
else
    h1 hello user
```

Normally it is compiled in server if I use **{"name" : "Bob"}** but I want to change in client if I use **{"name" : "Bean"}** it should give me "**hello user**". How to use both server and client side simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jade template is compiled to javascript function.

You can use `jade -c -p . < template.jade > template.js` to compile it using command line or `jade.compileFileClient(template.jade)` to compile it inside of your server-side javascript code.

After that just include it (with jade-runtime.js) from your client-side script and call `template({name:'Bob'})` from there, and you'll get html.

Comment: Where can I get the **jade-runtime.js**.